# Need to timeout driver.get() after some time interval

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am checking `PageLoad` time of website say `moneycontrol`, so its taking to much time to load.

Now I want terminate `driver.get()` if it passes 3 min next step will be `driver.close()` to close the session.

**code:**

```
driver.get("https://www.moneycontrol.com")
```

Appreciate help and suggestions.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question ? what mean by terminate driver.get ? what will be the next step ?

Comment: I mean if driver.get(url) is taking more then 3 min to load the page then driver.close should get instantiated

Comment: Which language ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9731291/631619

Answer (score 1):

You can set a page load timeout of 3 minutes for your URL:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Does it will work for headless browser ?

Comment: Yes it does with html unit driver

Answer (score 0):

You can use a explicit wait, it verifies constantly if your webe element is present and if that doesn't occur it pass to the next step

`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = driver.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
/// action`

Comment: your description is about *explicit* waits, and then the example you gave is for *implicit* waits.